# Delete directories with files containing specific string in PowerShell

Tags: powershell

Trying with Windows PowerShell to delete all directories that contain a XML-file with a specific content. Getting as far as listing all the files containing the correct pattern with

```
ls -r -Filter *.xml | ?{ $_ | Select-String -Pattern "ACC_cont"}
```

but can´t get the paths from the output and delete the directory and all it´s content. There might be more than one direcotry with a XML-file with the right pattern, and I like to delete them all.

Comment: instead of using `Select-String`, use a filter cmdlet like `Where-Object` - that will output fileinfo objects instead of match objects. THEN use the resulting fileinfo objects to perform other steps.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try the following:

```
Get-ChildItem -Recurse -Filter *.xml | 
  Select-String -List -Pattern "ACC_cont" |
    Remove-Item -Recurse -LiteralPath { Split-Path -Parent $_.Path } -WhatIf
```

`-WhatIf` previews the operation; remove it to perform actual deletion.

- `Select-String` directly accepts file-info objects output by `Get-ChildItem` from the pipeline.

  - `-List` makes `Select-String` stop after the 1st match in a file, which improves efficiency.
- The match-info objects output by `Select-String` have a `.Path` property that contains the input file path, so `Split-Path -Parent $_.Path` gets a matching file's director path.
- Passing `Split-Path -Parent $_.Path` inside a script block (`{ ... }`) to `Remove-Item`'s `-LiteralPath` parameter is instance of a delay-bind script block that provides parameter values derived dynamically from each input object, so that `Remove-Item -Recurse` removes every directory in which a matching XML file was found.

Comment: I´ll mark it as answered - but as a related question; any tips on how to limit to only include XML-files that were created >3 month ago.

Comment: Thanks, @DanielDellham - no worries about the up-vote (you'll be able to do that once you have >= 15 points). As for your follow-up question: generally, please post a _new_ question, though in this case I suspect existing ones may have the answer you need; in short: `Get-ChildItem -Recurse -Filter *.xml | Where-Object CreationTime -lt (Get-Date).AddMonths(-3)`